# jOOQ get table name from Result<R>

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I'm trying to retrieve the underlying MySQL table name, from a jOOQ **Result**.

Here's my best attempt, as a helper function:

```
private <R extends Record> String tableNameOf(Result<R> result) {
  return result.recordType().toString();
}
```

This returns `"database"."table_name"."first_column_name"`

This is purely for generating an error message, so for now I just grabbed it with a regex.

But I'm curious that I wasn't able to find a proper way to get at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `Result` doesn't know `Table`

First off, do note that a `Result` has no idea of a `Table` in principle! A `Result` is just a bunch of columns / records that was produced by an arbitrary `Select` statement. It may well include only expressions like `A + B` or `1` or `NULL`, which are not linked to any physical tables.

#### If you *know* you produced a `Result` from a physical table

Of course, you may *know* that a given `Result` was produced from a physical table, e.g. by using [`DSLContext.selectFrom()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#selectFrom-org.jooq.Table-). In that case, your generic `R` type shouldn't be bound to [`Record`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html) but to [`TableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableRecord.html).

One possible implementation could be:

```
private <R extends TableRecord<R>> String tableNameOf(Result<R> result) {
    return ((TableRecord<?, ?>) result.field(0)).getTable();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my scenario, and it turns out, there were multiple instances in my codebase where I had a totally impossible expectation: retrieving a table name from the result of a custom ("not-table-record") query. This reinforces why I like jOOQ so much: it's made explicit what is otherwise left for trial-by-error.